# Facebook comments custom css issue

Tags: css, facebook, iframe

I would like to ask how can I, or if it is even possible to customise css of facebook comments box. I have tried this CSS, but it didnt work.

```
.fb_iframe_widget, .fb_iframe_widget span, .fb_iframe_widget span iframe[style] {
   width: 100% !important;}
```

Is it even possible to modify the comments box?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: no, social plugins are "black boxes", you can only change stuff that is available with officially known parameters. also, it´s not allowed to change the appearance of social plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Those plugins render as an iframe that loads its content from a different domain, so you don’t have access to it via your own JavaScript or CSS.

The settings mentioned in the documentation are the only way for you to configure how this plugin behaves and looks, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#settings

Comment: Oh ok, I understand that. Thanks for reply.